# Unsigned 16 and 64 bit integers

Tags: java, type-conversion, java-7, network-protocols, primitive-types

How do you produce a 16 bit unsigned integer and a 64-bit unsigned integer in Java? This question is related to implementing a standard. I am not in a position to change the spec.

Other perhaps relevant bits of the spec. this question is related to:

- most significant bit MUST be 0.
- must be expressed in network byte order.

Application context: The number (in either form) represents the length of data being sent. The length can be big or small. I've first found the length of the message to be sent as a long.

So I'm starting with: `long length = getLength();`

I then need to convert the long variable "length" to either of the two above, depending on how big it is. In the end, I'm pretty sure I'll need to do a `.getBytes()` when I send the length. The recipient will interpret as described above.

Comment: In Java, a `short` is mandated to be 16-bit, and `long` is mandated to be 64-bit.  They're signed types, but you specify that the msb will always be 0, so that shouldn't matter. Is this sufficient?

Comment: What do you mean with "produce" do you want to write it as binary data into a stream? What is wrong with keeping it as the "long length"?

Comment: Yes. I have to write it to a stream. I tried sending the long, but it didn't work. The recipient choked. The receiver doesn't seem to have a problem getting messages when sent by other already developed senders. I've added a sentence to my question for clarity. I can't change the spec.

Comment: @Roger: Then you need to include information about the stream that your application produces, compared to one produced by an existing application (that works).

Comment: How does the receiver know which of the two representations you send?

Comment: @Roger F. Gay - you can't change the spec, but you certainly CAN explain the context better than you did.

Comment: It's in a UTF-8 byte stream. Does that help?

Comment: @josefx (I've solved this problem but thought I'd answer for the record.) There's a limit to the number that 16 bit can represent. If it's bigger, it has to be 64-bit. There's a header on each message that provides a code (no matter which end the message comes from) that indicates which one is being used on an incoming message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the most significant bit must be zero, then the number is the same whether it is signed or unsigned (assuming a two's complement representation).  So for instance, 16 bit integers with the MSB zero represent the numbers from `0` to `32767` inclusive.

Assuming that you are writing to an `OutputStream` and that your definition of "network order" is most significant byte first, then you need to do something like this:

```
public void writeShort(OutputStream os, short s) throws IOException {
    os.write((byte) (s >> 8));
    os.write((byte) s);
}
```

and

```
public void writeLong(OutputStream os, long l) throws IOException {
    os.write((byte) (l >> 56));
    os.write((byte) (l >> 48));
    os.write((byte) (l >> 40));
    os.write((byte) (l >> 32));
    os.write((byte) (l >> 24));
    os.write((byte) (l >> 16));
    os.write((byte) (l >> 8));
    os.write((byte) l);
}
```

Note that these works for signed and unsigned integers.  (Or to be more precise for the Java context, they work if the argument *represents* a signed or unsigned integer.)

Comment: Thanks a million. I generalized and send on return:

Comment: int shift=8;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      bytes[i] = (byte)(l >> (shift*(n-1-i)));
    }

Answer (score 1):

Java has no unsigned datatypes (see here: http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAndUnsignedTypes.html)

int has 32bit, long has 64bit, short has 16bit

is it so bad to store it all just as long?

Comment: "Java has no unsigned datatypes." Yes. I know. Therein lies the problem I'm facing. It's a requirement in the app.

Comment: @Roger: But you've said that the msb is always 0, so it doesn't matter.